# JavaScript into jQuery Convert

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've some raw JavaScript code and I want them to be re-written in jquery. So how do I do it?

```
(function(){

var parallax = document.querySelectorAll(".parallax"),
  speed = 0.1;

window.onscroll = function(){
[].slice.call(parallax).forEach(function(el,i){

  var windowYOffset = window.pageYOffset,
      elBackgrounPos = "100% " + (windowYOffset * speed) + "px";

  el.style.backgroundPosition = elBackgrounPos;

});
};

})();
```

Comment: what does your javascript do? Have you started the convertion?

Comment: It is used for making background image parallax while scrolling

Comment: Why would you want to make it slower by converting it to jQuery?

Comment: Easy and maintainable code with less lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/mckinleymedia/d3qt5p94/2/

And the code:

```
var parallax = $(".parallax"),
  speed = 0.1;

window.onscroll = function(){
  parallax.css('backgroundPosition','0 ' + (window.pageYOffset * speed) + "px");
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot William :)

Comment: No problem.  Glad I could help.

Comment: I've another issue can you pls find me a solution for it?

Comment: Sure.  What do you need?

Comment: In this http://codepen.io/firnasfaris10/pen/zrvKEZ I've created 2 boxes each containing click me button and after clicking the button I want the paragraph to display but the paragraph is display in both the boxes. Why is that? Is it because of same class or what can I do to over come that bug.

Comment: You want this in the clickme:
    $(this)
      .hide()
      .parent()
      .find('.show')
      .show();

Comment: Yes. That what I want :)